# Flutter setup failing, lib32stdc++6 won't install under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: flutter

I just sat down to try flutter out today and no matter what I've tried I can't get it working. I started by cloning out the repo, and then did a `flutter doctor` command, hoping it would work. The output looked something like this:

```
~/Development/Flutter$ flutter doctor
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine 7375a0f414bde4bc941e623482221db2fc8c4ab5...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 49.3M  100 49.3M    0     0  25.2M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 25.2M
Building flutter tool...
Downloading Material fonts...                                1.1s
Downloading package sky_engine...                            0.5s
Downloading common tools...                                  0.7s
Downloading linux-x64 tools...                               1.4s
Downloading android-arm-profile/linux-x64 tools...           0.7s
Downloading android-arm-release/linux-x64 tools...           0.7s
Downloading android-arm64-profile/linux-x64 tools...         0.7s
Downloading android-arm64-release/linux-x64 tools...         0.7s
Downloading android-arm-dynamic-profile/linux-x64 tools...   0.6s
Downloading android-arm-dynamic-release/linux-x64 tools...   1.1s
Downloading android-arm64-dynamic-profile/linux-x64 tools...  0.8s
Downloading android-arm64-dynamic-release/linux-x64 tools...  0.6s
Downloading android-x86 tools...                             0.9s
Downloading android-x64 tools...                             1.1s
Downloading android-arm tools...                             0.7s
Downloading android-arm-profile tools...                     0.7s
Downloading android-arm-release tools...                     0.7s
Downloading android-arm64 tools...                           0.9s
Downloading android-arm64-profile tools...                   0.7s
Downloading android-arm64-release tools...                   0.6s
Downloading android-arm-dynamic-profile tools...             0.8s
Downloading android-arm-dynamic-release tools...             0.6s
Downloading android-arm64-dynamic-profile tools...           0.8s
Downloading android-arm64-dynamic-release tools...           0.8s
Downloading Gradle Wrapper...                                0.4s
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.0.0, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
✗ Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.
  See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207 for more information
  On Debian/Ubuntu/Mint: sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
  On Fedora: dnf install libstdc++.i686
  On Arch: pacman -S lib32-libstdc++5

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

So to try and fix it I just did the recommended `sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6`. Which outputs like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32stdc++6 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04) but 8.2.0-12 is to be installed
            Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.18) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried everything I could find online to resolve this.

- `apt-get update`,
- removing my /etc/apt/sources.list file and having it recreated using the gtk-software-manager.
- `apt-get autoclean`,
- `apt-get autoremove`.
- `aptitude install lib32stdc++6`

  **NOTHING** is fixing it. Can someone please help me address this? I"d really like to give this a shot

Comment: It semms that you are trying to use the Flutter beta channel ([!] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.0.0).
Did you tried with the stable channel?.

Comment: Have you tried changing the file permission to executable ? 
`sudo chmod +x fileName`